# The use of tense with words ending -ed and -ing

Tags: tenses

When attempting to write a story, I get a little jumbled up, especially on tenses and the correct usage. In particular, I get confused over the usage of seemingly past tense (words ending in *-ed*) and words ending in *-ing* used in the same sentence. For example:

> Standing up straight, John relaxed tense muscles. Much like Sylar, he had been alarmed when first the beast appeared over the mountain’s crest. Slowly, it had trekked down the snow-laden landscape towards the two, pausing only when it was fifty or so feet away. There it perched itself upon its throne of snow and ice, staring with piercing eyes at the two humans who had intruded into its domain.

My beginning sentence starts in the present, but quickly slips to what the main character had seen just moments prior. I utilize what I believe is past-present (*had trekked*), then present (*pausing*). If someone could correct my sentences and explain why that would be much appreciated.

Comment: All your *-ing* forms (*standing*, *pausing*, *staring*) are tenseless **present participles**, not tensed finite verbs; the time reference of the clauses they head is inferred from the time reference of the finite clauses to which they are attached. The *had VERBed* constructions are **past perfects**, indicating that the event designated by the trailing past participles (*been*, *trekked*, *intruded*) occurred before the past time you are talking about with *relaxed*, *perched*).

Answer (score -1):

UNLESS you have edited the quoted paragraph in the original question to reflect the corrections suggested by the kind members, THE ORIGINAL PARAGRAPH IS PERFECTLY FINE FOR A NOVEL OR SHORT STORY! Don't worry about shifting to the  'had' form for once in a while, because it is always done by creative writers.

As long as you don't make glaring grammatical errors, there is a great deal of linguistic leeway available in writing fiction. Since I couldn't detect grammatical errors in the original paragraph in question, the detailed corrections so kindly and rigorously suggested appear optional.

Perfect grammar in terms of tenses is not really expected in creative writing, but internal consistency of tenses is certainly mandatory. DON'T BE SELF-CONSCIOUS ABOUT YOUR WRITING -- YOU ARE DOING JUST FINE! (Not to boast, but reading literary fiction is my long-time speciality, so I ought to know)

Answer (score -2):

Your assessment of the problem is mistaken.

Verbs beginning with "have" (*had trekked*) are called "perfect", and should be used when the action is complete.

The way your paragraph is written, it implies that all the movements of the beast had been completed *before* John stood up.  Is this what you meant?  John is stretching and relaxed, now, after the animal had approached him?

Off topic, but:

> John relaxed tense muscles

Are these *John's* tense muscles, or does he just have this effect on the muscles of onlookers?  If the former, say so.

> Slowly, it had trekked down the snow-laden landscape

1. That adverb should be next to the verb it modifies.  There are situations where you want to begin with an adverb -- typically, when the adverb logically describes the entire sentence, "Miraculously, I found my wallet exactly where I dropped it in the milling crowd" -- but this is not one of them.
2. "Trekking" is taking a long journey, not necessarily slowly and not necessarily by foot.  Consider "plod", "shuffled", "ambled" -- whatever near-synonym for "walked slowly" that best describes the motion of the animal as you see it.
3. "Laden" means "carrying".  A branch might be snow-laden; the bed of a snow-plow might be snow-laden; the edge of a cliff might be snow-laden.  A landscape is merely "snowy".

> There it perched itself upon its throne of snow and ice, staring with piercing eyes at the two humans who had intruded into its domain.

This is a mixed metaphor: perching means to sit or stand in the manner of a bird; a throne is the seat of a king.  Together they just don't work. Pick one.  The domain is the realm of a king, so if you keep "throne", you can keep domain, but if you go with "perch" you have to find a word to suggest the area a particular bird considers is own territory.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. This is a paragraph in the middle of the story, and it was meant to describe what John had just seen the wolf do, so John was relaxing his tense muscles, and I was trying to portray what the wolf had just done prior to him relaxing.

Comment: I also appreciate the suggestions for word changes. I'll look into what words I can change out to make the story make more sense in its description and actions.

Comment: I made the following changes. Please let me know if it still is wrong or makes little sense.

Comment: Standing up straight, John relaxed tense muscles. Much like Sylar, he had been alarmed when first the beast appeared over the mountain’s crest. Just moments ago, it had slowly descended the snow-filled landscape towards the two, pausing only when it was fifty or so feet away. There it settled itself upon its throne of snow and ice, staring with piercing eyes at the two humans who had intruded into its domain.

Comment: Did you see how little you have changed from the original paragraph! That means the original paragraph is ALREADY FINE.

Comment: @EnglishStudent -- it does **not** mean that.  The difference between the right word and almost the right word is the difference between lightning and the lightning bug.

Comment: In fact I agree with you, but not all creative writers are equally fastidious in their choice of words,  and many (especially beginners) can become quite inhibited if they get self conscious with their language. I am not a creative writer myself, and fully agree that there is NO SUBSTITUTE FOR THE JUST RIGHT WORD!

Comment: I appreciate both comments. While I realize in creative writing I do not need to strictly adhere to set rules (many authors I've read stick to their style, but change some things up), I am looking for good critique. I realize, for example, snow-laden landscape is not, strictly speaking, being used as was intended, but laden means covered with, and so telling someone a snow-laden landscape in loose terms is just the land covered by snow. I prefer the critique, though, so my sentences do not confuse the reader. I was also thinking of getting rid of perch, which helped confirm I should. Thanks.

Comment: My original question of whether or not how I was describing what John had just seen was answered, and even helped me change it to, Just moments prior, which might clarify things better, so the critiques helped. The added comments also gave me insight into using better descriptive words, which I'm quite busily doing so editing my chapters paragraph by paragraph. I just see I need to focus on this a lot more. Again, thanks for both the encouragement and critiques.

Comment: “I have been correcting the proofs of my poems. In the morning, after hard work, I took a comma out of one sentence. In the afternoon, I put it back again.”  -- Oscar Wilde _(attrib.)_

Comment: I have done the same for my own very infrequent poems -- especially in poetry, even a comma speaks volumes!